# concurrentHashMap has a volatile table , why need unsafe.getObjectVolatile() when get()

Tags: java

like the title; i think  unsafe.getObjectVolatile() when get() is  unnecessary ，and volatile table could make sure thread get the element up to date

```
transient volatile Node<K,V>[] table;


public V get(Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> e, p; int n, eh; K ek;
    int h = spread(key.hashCode());
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (e = tabAt(tab, (n - 1) & h)) != null) {
        if ((eh = e.hash) == h) {
            if ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek)))
                return e.val;
        }
        else if (eh < 0)
            return (p = e.find(h, key)) != null ? p.val : null;
        while ((e = e.next) != null) {
            if (e.hash == h &&
                ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek))))
                return e.val;
        }
    }
    return null;
}


static final <K,V> Node<K,V> tabAt(Node<K,V>[] tab, int i) {
    return (Node<K,V>)U.getObjectVolatile(tab, ((long)i << ASHIFT) + ABASE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons:

1. The code is not accessing the value of `table` through the field `table` - rather, the reference is copied to a local variable called `tab` and accessed through that variable. Since that variable is not `volatile` (and local variables cannot be volatile), none of the memory model guarantees are granted.
2. The guarantees of `volatile` only apply if one thread A writes the volatile variable; other threads that read from the same volatile variable are guaranteed to then see all changes made by thread A. However, in this case, the variable `table` is not updated frequently - instead, the elements of the array to which `table` points are updated. But these elements are not `volatile` - in fact, Java does not support volatile array elements. But, with `Unsafe.getObjectVolatile` and `Unsafe.putObjectVolatile`, you can volatile semantics for array element access, event when you cannot directly declare an array of volatile elements in Java. And that's what is needed for this code.

Comment: if  get element by table[] could guarantee the visibility of element ? ,actully  it makes me confused that  get element by index like table[]  from a volatile array could get guarantees of visibility  or not ,

Comment: There is no such thing as a "volatile array". Normally, accessing an element from an array does not provide visibility guarantees of itself (if the reference to the array is volatile, then that access introduces some guarantees - but if you read the reference, and then write an element, then you have not written to a volatile field and you have not introduced any visibility guarantees). The methods in `Unsafe` act like there is such a thing as an array with volatile members, even though the language doesn't offer it.

Comment: your mean is    table[]  could guarantee the element's visibility but tab[] not ? ,